# Java 17 on jboss EAP 6.1

Tags: java, jboss, java-17

I'm trying to start my jboss EAP 6.1 installation with Java 17, but I receive this error:

```
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\Sviluppo\jboss-eap-6.1_prova17

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat  -Dexo.jcr.session.tracking.active=false -Xms512m -Xmx2g --add-opens java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dgatein.assets.version=4.0.7 -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-exo.xml -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false

===============================================================================

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider __redirected.__XMLInputFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:201)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:148)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:261)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:223)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:166)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.<clinit>(ModuleXmlParser.java:278)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder$1.run(LocalModuleFinder.java:144)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder$1.run(LocalModuleFinder.java:138)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.findModule(LocalModuleFinder.java:138)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:389)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:293)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:240)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222)
        at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:76)
        at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:70)
        at __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory.changeDefaultFactory(__DocumentBuilderFactory.java:77)
        at __redirected.__JAXPRedirected.changeAll(__JAXPRedirected.java:43)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:334)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:190)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class __redirected.__XMLInputFactory cannot access class com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export com.sun.xml.internal.stream to unnamed module @5d22bbb7
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:489)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at __redirected.__XMLInputFactory.<init>(__XMLInputFactory.java:112)
        ... 24 more
```

I've tried to use this solution, but it doesn't work:
[Is it possible to run Wildfly 10 on new jdk17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70129530/is-it-possible-to-run-wildfly-10-on-new-jdk17)

Comment: As best as I can see when JBoss EAP 6.1 was released in 2013 Java 8 didn't even exist, let alone 9, 11 or 17. Java 9 introduced a *major* change to class loading (with the module system) and later released further restricted legacy options. Since EAP is a application server and application servers tend to do "funny things with classloading" it's in the class of applications most likely to not be compatible with newer Java versions without major changes. My strong suspicion: there's no way in heck that you're going to run that ancient EAP version on Java 17.

Comment: Also: [this page](https://access.redhat.com/articles/111663) (and [the same for EAP 7](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2026253)).

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is a really old EAP version that came from before Java 9 you'd need to change the scripts a lot to be able to run it on a newer Java version